# typescript and webpack can't find relative tsx file?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I should start with npx tsc works fine and only webpack ts-loader is not compiling typescript for some reason(Does that point to webpack config then since tsconfig is correct for tsc?  not sure).

I have a [pull request](https://github.com/deanhiller/reactpatterns-all/pull/3) on an open source project I am trying to add webpack too. This pull request is nearly working(worked out a slew of issues) and [this article](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/understanding-the-modern-web-stack-webpack-devserver-react-typescript-4b9b) is what I was generally following(which did not 100% work) but it was generally a good article.

My last error(I think) I am trying to resolve is

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src'
resolve './App' in '/Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src'
  using description file: /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/package.json (relative path: ./src/App)

  no extension
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src/App doesn't exist
  .js
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src/App.js doesn't exist
  .json
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src/App.json doesn't exist
  .wasm
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src/App.wasm doesn't exist
  as directory
    /Users/dean/workspace/personal/reactpatterns-all/reactpatterns-react/src/App doesn't exist
```

My full [tsconfig file](https://github.com/deanhiller/reactpatterns-all/blob/0422cefb53cd23d5b514aaa40dadc9a5f37890f6/reactpatterns-react/tsconfig.json) is linked.  Is there some config I am doing wrong?
My full [webconfig](https://github.com/deanhiller/reactpatterns-all/blob/0422cefb53cd23d5b514aaa40dadc9a5f37890f6/reactpatterns-react/webpack.config.js) is linked.

This project is a playground to match a larger app so I could trim the problem down a bit and figure this out.  Any ideas on what is wrong here?

I locked all package.json to EXACT versions so anyone can reproduce with npx webpack on that branches pull request(I did not merge into master since I do not have it working yet).  This includes failing on incorrect node/npm/npx versions too.

Answer (score 1):

I found two more things that had to be done to fix it all.  In tsconfig, I had to have

- "jsx": "react-jsx" rather than "preserve" as article says

In webpack, I had to add this section

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts', '.html', '.scss'],
  modules: ['node_modules'],
},
```